# Histogram of RGB colored Images without using built-in functions of MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

I cannot figure out a way to create a histogram of each of the RGB colors separately without using any of the built in functions.  I need to create a function called my_hist(image) that outputs three different figures each with the individual RGB value.  Any amount of help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by any built-in function you mean you can't use imhist, hist, bar or stem for instance?

Comment: Start by figuring out how to make a histogram (using whatever functions you are permitted) out of a matrix.  Splitting an RGB image into three parts and running your personal `hist` function on each part ought to be the easy bit.

Comment: i meant imhist or hist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `imhist`, try this:

```
Im = imread('autumn.tif');
ImHistogram = zeros(3,256);
for jj = 1 : 3
    for ii = 0 : 255
        ImHistogram(jj,ii+1) = sum(sum(Im(:,:,jj) == ii));
    end
end
```

Each row shows the histogram of each RGB

However If you can use `imhist` you might do this:

```
Im = imread('autumn.tif');
ImHistogram = zeros(3,256);
for jj = 1 : 3
    ImHistogram(jj,:) = imhist(Im(:,:,jj));
end
```

Comment: Here's another solution using `accumarray` that I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830225/content-based-image-retrieval-and-precision-recall-graphs-using-color-histograms/25830848#25830848.  This computes a linear index for an RGB tuple should it fall between a certain range of colours, then uses `accumarray` to compute the histogram.  It converts the histogram into a 1D array though, so you can use similarity measures in an easier way.

Comment: Nice answer @rayryeng. It's kind of a shame you received only 1 upvote for it. +1 for me!

Comment: @Benoit_11 merci beaucoup! I don't think it got a lot of exposure because the tag was CBIR. Still thank you for the vote :)

Comment: Ça fait plaisir! I guess you read my profile to know I speak french :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Bien sûr!  Je sais que vous venez de Québec.  Quelle belle province!

Comment: @rayryeng- Oui en effet! Très jolie et très froide avec l'hiver qui arrive!