# Matlab: Creating a binned RGB histogram

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to implement the following Matlab function:

```
function hist = binnedRgbHist(im, numChannelBins)
```

Given an image `im` and a number between 1 and 256 `numChannelBins`, it should create a histogram sized `(numChannelBins)^3`.

For example, if `numChannelBins` is **2**, it should produce the following 8-sized histogram:

1. Number of pixels with `R <  128, G <  128, B <  128`
2. Number of pixels with `R <  128, G <  128, B >= 128`
3. Number of pixels with `R <  128, G >= 128, B <  128`
4. Number of pixels with `R <  128, G >= 128, B >= 128`
5. Number of pixels with `R >  128, G <  128, B <  128`
6. Number of pixels with `R >  128, G <  128, B >= 128`
7. Number of pixels with `R >  128, G >= 128, B <  128`
8. Number of pixels with `R >  128, G >= 128, B >= 128`

It is like creating a cube where each axis represents one of (R,G and B), where each axis is divided into 2 bins  => Finally there are 8 bins in the cube.

My questions:

- It there a built-in function for it?
- If not, how is it better to implement it in manners of runtinme using the GPU? Should I better iterate over the pixels once and create the histogram manually, or should I better iterate over the bins and each time count the number of pixels which satisfy the bin's conditions?

Comment: This question/answer may also be of interest.  I converted each RGB tuple to a single 1D linear index, then the colour histogram becomes a 1D array instead.  I also used `accumarray`, but the conversion from colour to index is what is important: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830225/content-based-image-retrieval-and-precision-recall-graphs-using-color-histograms/25830848#25830848

Answer (score 1):

[`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is very suited for this. Let

- `im`: input image;
- `N`: number of bins per color component.

Then

```
result = accumarray(reshape(permute(ceil(im/255*N), [3 1 2]), 3, []).', 1, [N N N]);
```

**How it works**

1. `ceil(im/255*N)` quantizes each color vaue to `1`, `2`, ..., `N`.
2. `reshape(permute(..., [3 1 2]), 3, []).'` transforms the quantized image into a three-column matrix where each row is a pixel and each column is a (quantized) color component.
3. `accumarray(..., 1, [N N N])` considers each row of that matrix as 3D index, and counts how many times each index appears, giving filling indices that don't appear with a `0`.

**Example 1**

Data:

```
>> N = 2;
>> im = randi(256,4,5,3)
im(:,:,1) =
   113   152   157    65   229
   138    71   215    39    41
    13   108   230   160   153
   142   128   125   220   214
im(:,:,2) =
   208   215   182    27   230
   205   161     8    95   180
   225    53    73   129    31
   103    97   160    83   255
im(:,:,3) =
   242    29   185    89    55
   202   225   156   174    96
   160   197    35    87   113
   244   176   146    85   120
```

Result:

```
result(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     3     4
result(:,:,2) =
     2     4
     3     2
```

It can be checked for example that there is only 1 pixel with all R,G,B less than 128.

**Example 2**

Data:

```
>> im = repmat(150,20,30,3);
>> N = 4;
```

Result:

```
result(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
result(:,:,2) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
result(:,:,3) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0   600     0
     0     0     0     0
result(:,:,4) =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

In this case all pixels belong to the same 3D-bin:

Answer (score 1):

I see @Luis Mendo gave a great one-liner solution as I was writing this. In case it provides some deeper intuition, my solution makes use of [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
im             = randi([1 255],[10,5,3]);  %// A random 10-by-5 "image" 
numChannelBins = 2;

[~,~,binR]=histcounts(im(:,:,1),[1 ceil((1:numChannelBins)*(255/numChannelBins))]);
[~,~,binG]=histcounts(im(:,:,2),[1 ceil((1:numChannelBins)*(255/numChannelBins))]);
[~,~,binB]=histcounts(im(:,:,3),[1 ceil((1:numChannelBins)*(255/numChannelBins))]);
hist=accumarray([binR(:) binG(:) binB(:)],1,[numChannelBins,numChannelBins,numChannelBins])
```

**Explanation:**

- the three calls to `histcounts` bin the red, green, blue pixels separately -- the third output `[~,~,binX]` of `histcounts` gives the bin index for each pixel
- `accumarray` accumulates all the unique index triplets